# Python urllib2 file upload problems

Tags: python, post, upload, urllib2

I'm currently trying to initiate a file upload with urllib2 and the [urllib2_file](http://fabien.seisen.org/python/urllib2_multipart.html) library. Here's my code:

```
import sys
import urllib2_file
import urllib2

URL='http://aquate.us/upload.php'
d = [('uploaded', open(sys.argv[1:]))]
req = urllib2.Request(URL, d)
u = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print u.read()
```

I've placed this .py file in my My Documents directory and placed a shortcut to it in my Send To folder (the shortcut URL is  ).

When I right click a file, choose Send To, and select Aquate (my python), it opens a command prompt for a split second and then closes it. Nothing gets uploaded.

I knew there was probably an error going on so I typed the code into CL python, line by line.
When I ran the `u=urllib2.urlopen(req)` line, I didn't get an error; 
[alt text http://www.aquate.us/u/55245858877937182052.jpg](http://www.aquate.us/u/55245858877937182052.jpg)

instead, the cursor simply started blinking on a new line beneath that line. I waited a couple of minutes to see if something would happen but it just stayed like that. To get it to stop, I had to press ctrl+break.

What's up with this script?

Thanks in advance!

[Edit]
Forgot to mention -- when I ran the script without the request data (the file) it ran like a charm. Is it a problem with urllib2_file?

[edit 2]:

```
import MultipartPostHandler, urllib2, cookielib,sys
import win32clipboard as w
cookies = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies),MultipartPostHandler.MultipartPostHandler)
params = {"uploaded" : open("c:/cfoot.js") }
a=opener.open("http://www.aquate.us/upload.php", params)
text = a.read()
w.OpenClipboard()
w.EmptyClipboard()
w.SetClipboardText(text)
w.CloseClipboard()
```

That code works like a charm if you run it through the command line.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Python 2.5 or newer, `urllib2_file` is both unnecessary and unsupported, so check which version you're using (and perhaps upgrade).

If you're using Python 2.3 or 2.4 (the only versions supported by `urllib2_file`), try running [the sample code](http://fabien.seisen.org/python/test.py) and see if you have the same problem.  If so, there is likely something wrong either with your Python or `urllib2_file` installation.

**EDIT:**

Also, you don't seem to be using either of `urllib2_file`'s two supported formats for POST data.  Try using **one** of the following two lines instead:

```
d = ['uploaded', open(sys.argv[1:])]
## --OR-- ##
d = {'uploaded': open(sys.argv[1:])}
```

Comment: You say that urllib2_file is unnecessary on python 2.5 and greater, but this functionality doesn't exist in python yet.  Based on http://bugs.python.org/issue3244, multipart/form-data uploads may be here in 2.7, but that's not released yet.

Comment: I haven't looked at the problem since I posted this more than a year ago, but at the time, I was able to duplicate urllib2_file's functionality in Python 2.6 and even the library's page says it is only needed for Python 2.3 and 2.4.  I can only assume that bug refers to some separate (but probably closely related) issue.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, there's a third way to run Python programs.

From cmd.exe, type `python myprogram.py`.  You get a nice log.  You don't have to type stuff one line at a time.

Second, check the [urrlib2](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-urllib2.html) documentation.  You'll need to look at [urllib](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-urllib.html), also.

A Request requires a URL and a urlencoded encoded buffer of data.

> data should be a buffer in the
>   standard
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   format. The urllib.urlencode()
>   function takes a mapping or sequence
>   of 2-tuples and returns a string in
>   this format.

You need to encode your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still on Python2.5, what worked for me was to download the code here:

http://peerit.blogspot.com/2007/07/multipartposthandler-doesnt-work-for.html

and save it as MultipartPostHandler.py

then use:

```
import urllib2, MultipartPostHandler

opener = urllib2.build_opener(MultipartPostHandler.MultipartPostHandler())
opener.open(url, {"file":open(...)})
```

or if you need cookies:

```
import urllib2, MultipartPostHandler, cookielib

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj), MultipartPostHandler.MultipartPostHandler())
opener.open(url, {"file":open(...)})
```